# Show a fixed number of decimals in expression for vector categorized styling

Tags: qgis, vector, style, categorized-renderer, qgis-expression

So I am creating a categorized styling using an expression involving float numbers.

The results looks like this

[image]

The first row is displayed as "0 - 0.2m"

Is there a way to set in the expression `Dmin || ' - ' || Dmax || 'm'` a fixed number of decimals to display for the float attributes Dmin and Dmax so the result would look like "0.00 - 0.20m" and have the same number of decimals for all categories?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `format_number()` to format your number to the desired number of decimal places.

```
format_number("dmin",2) || ' - ' || format_number("dmax",2) ||'m'
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That was what I was looking for.
Many thanks @she_weeds!